# Call to a member function move() on null in laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I'm new to laravel. I get the following error when uploading a file:

> Call to a member function move() on null

```
$file = $request->file('img');
$destinationPath = base_path('\public\img');
$file->move($destinationPath . $file->getClientOriginalName());

$dealer = new Dealer([
    'firstname' => $request->get('firstname'),
    'lastname'  => $request->get('lastname'),
    'email'     => $request->get('email'),
    'phoneno'   => $request->get('phoneno'),
    'img'       => $request->get('img'),
]);
```

Comment: $dealer = new Dealer([
                    'firstname'      =>  $request->get('firstname'),
                    'lastname'       =>  $request->get('lastname'),
                    'email'          =>  $request->get('email'),
                    'phoneno'        =>  $request->get('phoneno'),
                    'img'            =>  $request->get('img')
                ]);

Comment: did you try by adung "\" at last `base_path('\public\img\');`

Comment: This error is saying that `$file` is null which means that `img` is not getting uploaded correctly. Please can you show the form you're using to upload the image. If you're using any javascript for this process please can you include that as well.

Comment: hi Ross Wilson i didn't using js

Comment: image will stored but it not moving...my root folder (\public\img')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if ($request->hasFile('img')) {
        $image = $request->file('img');
       //  print_r($image);
        $image_name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
       //  echo $image;
       //  exit(0);
        $destinationPath = base_path('Uploads');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $image_name);
     $dealer = new Dealer([
                 'firstname'      =>  $request->get('firstname'),
                 'lastname'       =>  $request->get('lastname'),
                 'email'          =>  $request->get('email'),
                 'phoneno'        =>  $request->get('phoneno'),
                 'img'            =>  $image_name,
             ]);
             $dealer->save();
             Session::flash('msg','Data Added successfully');
             Session::flash('type','success');
             return redirect('dealer-master');
        //         //  echo $image;
        //         //  exit(0);
        //          $destinationPath = base_path('  Uploads');
        //          $image->move($destinationPath, $image_name);
      } 
        else {                          
        Session::flash('msg','Please Check the data');
        Session::flash('type','fail');
        return redirect('dealer-master');
        // echo $request;
         }
```

I Findout my mistake This is working good Thank U Guys...!

Answer (score 2):

Why dont You Try it like this ?

```
 if ($request->hasFile('img')) {
        $image = $request->file('img');
        $teaser_image = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $img);
            } else {
dd('Request Has No File');
}
```

and For Your Store  :

```
 $dialer = Dialer::create([
 'firstname' => $request->get('firstname'),
    'lastname'  => $request->get('lastname'),
    'email'     => $request->get('email'),
    'phoneno'   => $request->get('phoneno'),
    'img'       => $request->get('img') ?? null,
]);
```

You Can remove ??null for making sure that you get The image And store it in database but You can Even place It To make it Optional for the User To insert img or not . hope this helps

**EDIT**

According to your comment i guess you may have 2 problems :
first one be sure that you have and input that named 'img' that sends the image and the secound is that be sure to add the multi enctype to your form so that form can send image like below :

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

so your form should be like this :

```
<form action="someRoute" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: else part only run

Comment: $dialer part have no path

Comment: @mydeen it means that u dont send the image check the answer i updated that

Comment: You Can Remove The $dialer Too its fine i just place it there for returning the created object and show it to user

Answer (score 0):

It's work form me

```
if($request->img){
     $fileName = time() . '.' . $request->img->extension();
     $request->img->move(storage_path('app/public/img'), $fileName);
 }
$dealer = new Dealer([
    'firstname' => $request->get('firstname'),
    'lastname'  => $request->get('lastname'),
    'email'     => $request->get('email'),
    'phoneno'   => $request->get('phoneno'),
    'img'       => $fileName ?? null,
]);
$dealer->save();
```